# Error empty response when logging in magento admin

Tags: magento, admin

I really stuck on this issue, everytime i log in into magento admin, it's give me an **ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE** on *google chrome* and **Connection reset** on *Mozilla*.

The shop is still accessable, but it's load very slowly. It's working fine before, and suddenly become like this.

I can't find a similiar issue like this, mostly are the shop that return an empty response and they still can access the admin page and it's caused of ***enabling flat category/products set up.***

I'm not sure if client enabling the **flat category/products**. If it so, what table should i edit using *phpmyadmin*?

since i can't access the admin page, or there are another thing that cause this? *some error code, some files missing in admin directory or htaccess thing, actually i'm not doing changes on htaccess before*. Really need your help.

Comment: Any message in magento or server error logs?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i'm not enabling the error log in magento, but, i found this message in error log server :

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Mage_Adminhtml_Helper_Data' not found in /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php

i'm checking the helper php file in : app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Data.php
but it's still exist.

Answer (score 1):

Restarting apache and mysql worked for me

> service httpd restart
>
> service mysqld restart

Hope this helps.

Comment: If restarting httpd didn't solve the issue, consider stop then start, i.e. `service httpd stop` then `service httpd start`, I faced this issue recently